# Running and reporting Visual Studio 2012 Code analysis in TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, teamcity

What is the best way to run and report Visual Studio 2012 code analysis in TeamCity?

Answer (score 5):

Since FxCop or Code Analysis integrates directly into MsBuild, it's probably as simple as adding `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=Always` or `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=True` to the MsBuild commandline when building the project. Since this will generate standard compiler warnings,   TeamCity should pick them up automatically.

Comment: I would like to upvote this 10 times! I lost a few hours trying it by difficult ways until I found your answer. I just put the parameter on my first build step (MsBuild) and created a new "Failure Condition" finding by specific text in build log. Very thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010+ Code Analysis is (based on) FxCop 10.0. You can simply add a 'FxCop' build runner type build step.

When the 'Report XSLT file' setting is configured the build runner will output a HTML report. FxCop 10.0 includes a default XSLT file under '%system.FxCopRoot%/Xml/FxCopReport.xsl' to generate a default HTML report.